# Inheriting operator= and constructor but also add an extra wrapper assignment

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

I have the following struct:

```
struct Feedback : public TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>
{
    using TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>::TaggedUnion;
    using TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>::operator=;

    bool isError = false;
};
```

... which inherits TaggedUnion's operator =, allowing me to write the following:

```
Feedback a = Feedback1Idx();
Feedback b = String();
Feedback c = Feedback();
Feedback d = b;
```

In the examples above, I would like a.isError to be true, b.isError to be true, but c.isError to be false (and d.isError to be true because b.isError is true).
In other words, anytime an **inherited** operator = is used, I would like .isError to be switched to true.

How can I achieve this? *(without having to add a constructor/assignment operator for each template parameter I add to TaggedUnion<>)*

Comment: Note that *none* of the examples uses any overloaded assignment operator. They are all constructor calls.

Comment: You achieve this by defining an explicit assignment operator, instead of inheriting one?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Indeed, however in the future I will add more template parameters to TaggedUnion<>, and so I would like this to be automatic if it is possible. I am not opposed to defining my own operator, this is more about "how do I define it in such a way that it wraps around the inherited operator?" as per the title; otherwise it would mean I would have to add an overload anytime I add a parameter to TaggedUnion<>

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is true, however the same problems applies, but with constructors instead of assignment operators. Ideally, I would define the same behavior for both of them.

Comment: So, have your user-defined operator call `TaggedUnion::operator=` explicitly?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Right, but what's the syntax for TaggedUnion::operator=, and TaggedUnion::TaggedUnion, both within Feedback?

Comment: `TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>::operator=` and `TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>::TaggedUnion`, just like the shown code says.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik right, but I don't -always- want to call them, for instance in the copy constructor Feedback::Feedback(const Feedback& other) I would not call it. Does this mean I would use templates + templates specialization? With what you propose, I would have to define Feedback::Feedback(const Feedback1Idx& other) as well as Feedback::Feedback(const String& other), and keep adding more with every template parameter I add.

Comment: There are various techniques for addressing that, involving templates. That would be a separate question. For this question: no, you can't define an assignment operator like that, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is not a separate question. That is this question. It's literally what I'm asking... A solution to the above problem, which would involve templates (because I am unwilling to use virtual).

Comment: The question refers to the assignment operator, and not to any constructor, as in your prior comment. Assignment operators are not constructors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This kind of behavior is why people dislike stackoverflow. People having a problem obviously don't define their problem with textbook precision, because if they had textbook precision then they wouldn't have the problem. If you're not gonna answer the question that's fine. But if you need it so bad, I can add "how can I achieve this WITHOUT HAVING TO DECLARE A NEW OPERATOR EACH TIME I ADD A PARAMETER" if it satisfies your snobby behavior. Also, it concerns constructors just as much as assignment operators, as they would both do the exact same thing, so that is irrelevant.

Comment: The original question was, quoting: "anytime an inherited operator = is used, I would like .isError to be switched to true". I'm quite content to let everyone else judge whether this interpretation would be reasonably inferred, from that. As far as I can see: is there some magic wand somewhere that can be waived, to make the inherited `=` operator work like this? The answer is still "no", simple and short.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Again. I am not denying the most objective interpretation of the question was different from what you claim it to be. I am simply stating that you are trying to optimize being as close to the question as possible, without taking into consideration that people may not express their problem perfectly in the first try. Please, be more practical, instead of pedantic. Regardless, I have edited the question now, for your pleasure.

Comment: Unfortunately, the alternative to "being as close the question as possible" is utterly wasting everyone's time. For example, a template constructor that participates in overload resolution only if the template type is one of the `TaggedUnion` types is fairly straightforward. But that only works if there's no need to support implicit conversions to any of 'em. Is implicit conversion support required? Only you know that. So, let's say I invest the time to write out this constructor. You try it, and discover that a bunch of stuff fails to compile now. I wasted a lot of time.

Comment: Hmmm... That seems to be what my prior comments were all about: more information and clarification. Anyway, I'm looking forward to seeing what your solution turned out to be.

Comment: Well, as I explained: C++ is not that simple. You did not spell out whether or not the overloaded template should or should not participate in overload resolution unless the template parameter can be used, explicitly or implicitly to construct one of the variant values. Your answer does not restrict overload resolution participation which, in specific situation result in compilation failures. Unfortunately, due to a lack of a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste and verify, an authoritative answer would not be possible without access to the full code. Which only you have.

Comment: Well, yes I did. There is still no way to make the inherited `=` overload, via the `using` directive, work the way you wanted it would work. If anything, a user-defined `=` overload is required. Like in your answer. And nobody blamed you for anything. I simply stated that I declined to attempt to guess and fill in the blanks, making unwaranted assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution:

```
struct Feedback : public TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>
{
    bool isError = false;

    Feedback() = default;

    Feedback(const Feedback& _other) = default;

    template<typename TYPE>
    Feedback(const TYPE& _other)
    : TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>(_other)
    {
        this->isError = true;
    }

    Feedback& operator=(const Feedback& _other) = default;
    
    template<typename TYPE>
    Feedback& operator=(const TYPE& _other)
    {
        this->isError = true;
        TaggedUnion<Feedback1Idx, String>::operator=(_other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

A small thing to note: the compiler will probably scream at you if you attempt to do `Feedback a = int`, or some other type that is not in the inherited type.

Aside from that, should be all good (tested it a bit).